# How to cancel sorting event in tablesorter plugin?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I wonder if that would be possible:

During an event I would like to check certain condition, if that condition is true, I would like to cancel the event right away.

In the case below, if this condition is met, I would like to disallow the user of sorting the table at all.

```
$(table).bind("sortBegin",function(e, table) { 
   if(condition_is_met){
     // ?? How to cancel the sortBegin?
   }

});
```

Is something like this possible in jquery?

**Update**:

Apologies,

1)I thought tagging `tablesorter` would be clear enough to indicate which plugin I am using. ;) Anyway `tablesorter` it is. Thanks

2) I would like to disallow sorting of any kind until the condition isn't met anymore.  I don't mind if the whole table would be stopped from sorting or only the current event.

Comment: use .on, delegate, .off to stop event to trigger, return false to stop event after it's being triggered

Comment: guys, if the question isn't clear, please let me know what I could do to improve it, other than just down voting it. I don't even know what is wrong with the question to be downvoted this way. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify: do you want the tablesorter plugin not to sort the table if the condition is met?

Comment: @Kave for a start you should tell us what plugin you're using.

Comment: @Alnitak it's in the tags.. http://tablesorter.com I think. The plugin just triggers the event and doesn't react to it... so it cannot be done without modification or throwing exception

Comment: `unbind` your function ..

Comment: @Esailija That plugin uses "startSort", not "sortBegin"

Comment: `event` and code being run that triggers the event are different things. Not clear what you want to cancel

Comment: @Alnitak it's sortBegin in a later version https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js#L679. Regardless, the same deficiency is here as well, no preventDefault support.

Comment: Question is now updated. wow very trigger happy with downvotes today :)

Comment: @Kave you have use http://jquery.com/ for tutorial how to `unbind` use

Comment: @Alnitak it does use sortbegin http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/#Events

Comment: @Kave the version I found didn't.  Anyhow, like Easilija says you can't do this within that event, since the plugin doesn't do anything useful with that event - it just fires it for "informational" purpose.  You just have to prevent the plugin from becoming enabled until your condition is satisfied, and disable it again if it's not satisfied.

Comment: @Alnitak Alright thanks. You can now remove your downvote ;-)

Comment: @Kave I already did - the ones you've got now weren't mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the plugin didn't think about `preventDefault` - you either need to modify it or throw an exception to abort the 
call stack, which should be effectively the same as a well supported `preventDefault` but uglier.

```
$(table).bind("sortBegin",function(e, table) { 
   if(condition_is_met){
     throw new Error("");
   }

});
```

IIRC, `.trigger()` in jQuery works synchronously, if this is true then this will work.

If you want to modify the plugin, this is how you can add support for `preventDefault`:

```
var e = $.Event( "sortBegin" );
$this.trigger(e, $t0);
if( !e.isDefaultPrevented() ) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // set css for headers
        setHeadersCss($t0);
        multisort($t0);
        appendToTable($t0);
    }, 1);
}
```

Now when the client of the code calls `e.preventDefault()` in a sortBegin-event, the plugin would not proceed with sorting.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. I better stick to `throw error` for now, since it would be otherwise a pain whenever I had to update the plugin. I let the plugin writer know, maybe he can fix this in code for the proper way.  Thanks

Comment: Btw, you can disable client-side sorting by setting the [`serverSideSorting`](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/#serversidesorting) option to `true`.

Answer (score -2):

jQuery provide unbind function to unbind an event from a selector

Here is an example

```
$('#foo').unbind('click');
```